# EL is not interpreted and appears plain vanilla in generated HTML output

Tags: jsp, struts, jstl, el

I am using Struts1 and JSP. I can access the form property using the `<bean:write>` tag but I can't do it with the JSTL. Why not? My form is a `DynaActionForm`.

This statement works:

```
<bean:write name="myForm" property="origin"/>
```

This does not work, displays ${myForm.map.origin} plain vanilla:

```
<c:out value="${myForm.map.origin}"/>
```

This does not work either, displays ${myForm.origin} plain vanilla:

```
<c:out value="${myForm.origin}"/>
```

Comment: It's a legacy system and I am doing some enhancements. I guess they've always used struts1 and they don't want to change it to other framework from fear of breaking the system.

Comment: Tried it with just "origin" and it doesn't work. It prints ${origin}

Comment: I'm not sure why you tagged this question with `[javascript]`, I've removed it, but I just wanted to assure that Java/JSP and JavaScript have **absolutely nothing** to do with each other expect of the 1st 4 characters in the language name. Check the Wikipedia entries about both languages to learn about the strict difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can happen if there's somewhere a Servlet/JSP, JSTL and/or web.xml version mismatch. During Servlet 2.3/JSP 1.2, EL was part of JSTL 1.0. During Servlet 2.4/JSP 2.0, EL was moved from JSTL to JSP and JSTL 1.1 shipped without EL. The web.xml version declaration dictates the Servlet/JSP version currently used and must be supported by the target container.

So, if you're using JSTL 1.0 on Servlet 2.4/JSP 2.0, or are using JSTL 1.1 on Servlet 2.3/JSP 1.2, then you will face exactly this problem. Also, if you're using JSTL 1.1 on Servlet 2.4/JSP 2.0, but the web.xml is declared conform Servlet 2.3 (or doesn't contain any version declaraion), then you will also face exactly this problem.

All is explained in [our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info). You can also find download links to the right JSTL versions and examples of the right version-specific web.xml declarations in there.

Another possible cause is that you've a `<%@page isElIgnored="true"%>` declaration in top of the JSP or `<jsp-config><el-ignored>true</el-ignored></jsp-config>` in `web.xml`, but that's a too obvious cause to be overlooked.

Comment: You are right about your first assumption about ${} being interpreted as plain text.I checked the version of my servlet using servletContext.getMajorVersion() and servletContext.getMinorVersion and I got 2 and 5 respectively. Does it mean I am using servlet 2.5? If that's the case then the problem is something else?

Comment: In this web application, there are other pages where they have used jstl and it has worked. It's only this particular jsp page that I am working with that has the problem. In my web.xml file, there is no mention of any version.

Comment: I finally solved it. You asked me if I had this statement in my jsp <%@page isElIgnored="true"%> . I didn't. I added this statement to my jsp but changed the true value to false and it worked. Would you happen to know whay that would happen?

Comment: Apparently it's globally configured in `web.xml` as `<el-ignored>true</el-ignored>`.