# Why does the existence of web.xml keep my JSP from working?

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I have a jsp file that looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>location: ${pageContext.request.scheme}://${pageContext.request.serverName}:${pageContext.request.serverPort}${pageContext.request.contextPath}/</div>
    <div>(should have "verdagon.net" somewhere in there)</div>

    <div>Included stuff should appear below here:</div>
    <jsp:include page="toinclude.html"/>
</body>
</html>
```

and when I have no web.xml in my WEB-INF directory, it outputs correctly:

```
location: http://verdagon.net:80/strnowebxml/
(should have "verdagon.net" somewhere in there)
Included stuff should appear below here:
I'm included!
```

Yet when I add a WEB-INF directory, and I put a bare-bones web.xml, with just this in it,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
</web-app>
```

with that web.xml just being present, I get this output:

```
location: ${pageContext.request.scheme}://${pageContext.request.serverName}:${pageContext.request.serverPort}${pageContext.request.contextPath}/
(should have "verdagon.net" somewhere in there)
Included stuff should appear below here:
I'm included!
```

**The problem:** Those dollar-sign replacements aren't happening.

**The weird thing:** I know JSP is running, because that jsp:include is doing fine.

Anyone know why the JSP works when there's no web.xml, then breaks when I add it in?

Comment: Try using the following in your JSP: `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>` and see if this works. I am assuming that when you use `web.xml` this property is by-default `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! It turns out there was a version mismatch. The global web.xml, in tomcat/conf/web.xml, had the top line as:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
version="2.4">
```

but my top line was

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
```

**the answer:** The versions were different! The top one was 2.4, the bottom one was 3.0. Once I changed my 3.0 one to 2.4, the substitutions happened properly.

(For anyone else having a similar problem, these answers may help you:)

[EL is not interpreted and appears plain vanilla in generated HTML output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411877/el-is-not-interpreted-and-appears-plain-vanilla-in-generated-html-output)

[Expression Language in JSP not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168832/expression-language-in-jsp-not-working)